# Pasting with spaces added into heads of lines (analogy to comment-chars)?

Tags: vim, gvim

Please, consider a situation, where you find a nice example and want to copy it to your existing code to see, how it works.

The indentation is almost never right right away. If there are several lines, line-by-line editing can be tedious. On another question, there were hints on how to add spaces into a block of lines and on another, how to use :paste-option, which is used to control comment-characters when pasting. (Is this right?)

Can you use :paste or somehow in other way tell that when pasting, add, say 4 spaces into the front of every pasted line?

Late addition: I use "+gP quite often to paste a block of lines. Thus the :paste below sounds very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pasting, you can do:

```
'[>']
```

To shift the just-inserted text by `'shiftwidth'` columns. You can repeat with `.`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this one. Just have to make sure vim inserts spaces and not tabs.

Comment: @Gspia `:set expantab` for that

Comment: This works very well. First correct shiftwidth, then expandtab, after which intendation goes very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I always set paste to enabled prior to doing this:

```
:set paste
```

Then paste the example code into vim. Paste is typically off by default. See `:help paste` for more on the implications.

To undo the above:

```
:set nopaste
```

I'd check out this StackOverflow Q&A titled: [How do you paste with vim without code being commented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217007/how-do-you-paste-with-vim-without-code-being-commented) for other alternatives to this as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this one, I use quite often "+gP and a wild quess is that paste would be the shortest solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `]p` and `]<MiddleMouse>` commands work like `p`, but adjust the indent to the current line. So if you paste an unindented code snippet in the middle of a deep conditional, it should just fit.

Comment: I added "+gP to the question: anyhow I'll try also ]p-command, how it works.